# Error installing libgimp2.0, can't fix broken install cause GIMP and XSane conflict?

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies

I can't install new packages because of broken dependence:
`libgimp2.0`

When I try `apt --fix-broken install` or `apt-get install gimp libgimp2.0`

I get the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing the file /var/cache/apt/archives/libgimp2.0_2.99.1+om~7-0ubu18.04.2~ppa_amd64.deb (--unpack): trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libgimp-3.0.so.0.9901.0',  which is also in the package libgimp3.0 2.99.1+om~19-0ubu18.04.4~ppa
dpkg-deb: error: copied the subprocess was killed by the signal (broken pipe)
```

I think is a conflict between the libraries used by gimp and sane but I don't know how to fix it. I also tried `apt-get update` `apt-get full-upgrade` but it keep telling me that I need `libgimp2.0`

Answer (score 2):

force removing the conflicting package (assumed to be `libgimp3.0`) by

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-all libgimp3.0
```

then install the package again by

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: I did solve it just before with `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libgimp2.0_2.99.1+om~7-0ubu18.04.2~ppa_amd64.deb` as a comment on question n°383079 suggested. Still thanks for your answer @FangQ.